# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce514

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a file download code but i get this error when i start it in my projects. Only this code works perfectly fine. But in complex project this error occurred. Can you help about it ?
Here is download code

```
string fileUrl = @filePath + "\\" + _DownloadableProductFileName;
            string newFileName = _DownloadableProductFileName;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            fs.Close();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + newFileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            Response.End();
```

And the error code is

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce514.

Here error occurs.

```
get_responseData: function XMLHttpExecutor$get_responseData() {
    /// <value type="String" locid="P:J#Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor.responseData">The text of the response.</value>
    if (arguments.length !== 0) throw Error.parameterCount();
    if (!this._responseAvailable) {
        throw Error.invalidOperation(String.format(Sys.Res.cannotCallBeforeResponse, 'get_responseData'));
    }
    if (!this._xmlHttpRequest) {
        throw Error.invalidOperation(String.format(Sys.Res.cannotCallOutsideHandler, 'get_responseData'));
    }

    return this._xmlHttpRequest.responseText; //here throw error
},
```

Comment: what is filePath declared as? also what is it's value please show how you are assigning filePath. can you debug this as well and lets us know what line of code the error is happening.. you need to checkout your .aspx file where you are using javascript

Comment: filepath and fileName values are right. I have create a new project.I add a button to the page and button click event is exactly above.It works but in my main project its very complex, I'm getting this error.

filePath is a string and value = "D:\\Deneme\\C001\\Test.jpg"

Comment: if it works fine.. then why are you posting the code that works..? you are confusing me where in the code does that error code happen.. complex or not you should debug the code.. don't just "Code and GO" as we like to say..

Comment: I edit the questions. Error is in the ScriptResource.axd file

Comment: I would suggest looking at this link it explains the XMLHttpExecutor Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397459.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just for the protocol (two years late ;). The error occurs when your download code is placed inside an update panel performing an async postback. You must ensure that the request delivering a binary file always performs a synchronous postback so that the browser is able to  interprete the binary result file (and not the XMLHttpExecutor who expected html fragments).

**Solution:** Place the name of your Button as a [PostBackTrigger](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) or register the button with

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(yourButton)
```